# How to set model data in an Ember.js unit test for a controller

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data, ember-qunit

I'm trying to write a unit test to test my controller. I have a computed property that uses a computed property on the model.

I'm unsure of how to setup the test to load the data into the model.

Here I have my model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  roles: DS.hasMany('role'),

  isInstructor: function(){
    return this.hasRole('instructor');
  }.property('roles'),

  hasRole: function(role_name){
    var roles = this.get('roles');
    if(!Ember.isEmpty(roles)){
      return roles.any(function(role){
        return role.get('name') === role_name;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

And here I have my controller:

```
App.MyClassDetailsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  students: function () {
    return this.get('users').filter(function (user) {
      return !user.get('isInstructor');
    });
  }.property('content.users.@each')
});
```

And in my test when I setup the content for the controller I do this:

```
myClassDetailsController.set('model', Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
  id: 389,
  name: 'bfcoding 101',
  users: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [
      Ember.ObjectProxy.create({id: 1, name: 'Joe', roles: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: [Ember.ObjectProxy.create({name: 'instructor'})]})}),
      Ember.ObjectProxy.create({id: 2, name: 'vs', roles: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: [Ember.ObjectProxy.create({name: 'student'})]})}),
      Ember.ObjectProxy.create({id: 3, name: 'Volcano', roles: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: [Ember.ObjectProxy.create({name: 'student'})]})})
    ]
  })
}));
```

And that obviously doesn't load it correctly. Because when I call that students method:

```
myClassDetailsController.get('students.length')
```

It returns all of the users.

Here is a jsbin http://jsbin.com/zafod/1/

In the jsbin, when it filters over all the users, the isInstructor computed property never gets called because the model data was never loaded (I presume). When I make that call it comes back undefined.

So how do I load that data into the model?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still looking into Ryan's `ic-ajax` library, we opted not to use it in my code, but that's cause we've been writing ember tests for a year or so, so it didn't add a ton to our environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isInstructor` lives on instances of `App.User`, not on `Ember.ObjectProxy` instances.  You'd either need to create instances of `App.User` or just defined `isInstructor` on the proxy instance.

Personally I'd do the latter. In a perfect unit test world you are testing the controller, not `App.User` so everything else should be mocked or presumed working perfect.  Obviously as you switch to integration testing this all changes, but again, this is Unit Testing.

```
Ember.ObjectProxy.create({id: 1, isInstructor: true, name: 'Joe', roles: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: [Ember.ObjectProxy.create({name: 'instructor'})]})}),
```

http://jsbin.com/vavikuka/1/edit

Comment: ahh, good point. Since I already have model tests to make sure the isInstructor works, mocking it is better. I mocked it and all is well now. Thanks again!